# Aplicar datepicker a um input dinâmico com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Tenho um formulário onde pode ser adicionados vários campos com datepicker. Porém, ao adicionar um novo campo ao formulário, o datepicker do Jquery não é carregado.

Este é o JS responsável por clonar e adicionar os campos ao formulário:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

hideBtnDel();

function hideBtnDel() {
    if ($("#digitalCertificates .digitalCertificate").length <= 1) {
        $("#digitalCertificates .digitalCertificate .removeDigitalCertificate").addClass('disabled');
        $("#digitalCertificates .digitalCertificate .removeDigitalCertificate").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $("#digitalCertificates .digitalCertificate .removeDigitalCertificate").removeClass('disabled');
        $("#digitalCertificates .digitalCertificate .removeDigitalCertificate").prop('disabled', false);
    }
    removeDigitalCertificate();
}

function removeDigitalCertificate() {
    $(".removeDigitalCertificate").unbind("click");
    $(".removeDigitalCertificate").bind("click", function () {
        $(this).parents('.digitalCertificate').remove();
        hideBtnDel();
    });
}

$("#addDigitalCertificate").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    newDigitalCertificate = $("#digitalCertificates .digitalCertificate:first").clone();
    newDigitalCertificate.find("input[type='text']").val("");
    newDigitalCertificate.find("input[type=hidden]").val("");
    newDigitalCertificate.find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
    newDigitalCertificate.find("select").val("");
    newDigitalCertificate.insertAfter("#digitalCertificates .digitalCertificate:last");
    hideBtnDel();
});
```

Fazendo uma pesquisa, eu encontrei isso, que na teoria deveria resolver o problema, mas não funcionou, ele até entra na função, mas o datepicker não é aplicado (adicionei ele logo após o '$(document).ready(function() {...}' do bloco acima):

```
$(document).on('focus', '.datepicker', function () {
    console.log('teste');
    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
        nextText: 'Próximo',
        prevText: 'Anterior',
    });
});
```

Tem alguma outra forma de carregar esse datepicker dinâmicamente?

Comment: Tenta colocar `$("#digitalCertificates").datepicker()` onde é criado o clone.

Comment: @LeAndrade também já tentei isso, não funcionou.

Comment: Inclua a classe `datepicker` nos inputs onde vc quer que seja aplicado: `<input class="datepicker"....>`. Se já tiver outras classes, basta incluir ela: `<input class="datepicker outraClasse MaisOutra"...>`. Quando vc focar o input, automaticamente o datepicker será aplicado.

Comment: @sam Ao clonar o campo, as classe 'datepicker' também é clonada, então todos os inputs já vem com essa classe (se eu entendi direito o que você quis dizer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Após inserir o clone, remova a classe `hasDatepicker` do `input`. Essa classe é inserida pelo Datepicker e ao clonar o elemento com essa classe, o Datepicker está entendendo que ele já foi aplicado ao `input`, quando na verdade não o foi.

É só inserir esta linha após a inserção do clone (após o `insertAfter`):

```
$("#digitalCertificates .digitalCertificate:last")
.removeClass("hasDatepicker");
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#addDigitalCertificate").click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      newDigitalCertificate = $("#digitalCertificates .digitalCertificate:first").clone();
      newDigitalCertificate.insertAfter("#digitalCertificates .digitalCertificate:last");
      $("#digitalCertificates .digitalCertificate:last")
      .removeClass("hasDatepicker");
   });
   
   $(document).on('focus', '.datepicker', function () {
      $(this).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
      dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
      dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
      monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
      monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
      nextText: 'Próximo',
      prevText: 'Anterior',
      });
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="digitalCertificates">
   <input type="text" class="digitalCertificate datepicker">
</div>
<br>
<a href="#" id="addDigitalCertificate">Adicionar</a>
```

**Outra coisa:**

Inclua o parâmetro `event` na função do evento:

```
$("#addDigitalCertificate").click(function (event) {...
                                              ↑
```

Sem incluir o parâmetro, o `event.preventDefault();` não irá funcionar no Firefox, por exemplo.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Este bloco não funcionou '$("#digitalCertificates .digitalCertificate:last")
.removeClass("hasDatepicker");', mas eu substitui por este
'newDigitalCertificate.find('input.hasDatepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').removeAttr('id');' adicionado antes do 'insertAfter'.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu.